# Remote GPIO Control via. WiFi from the raspberry Pi

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, gpio

I heard about many techniques how to control the GPIO pins remotely. But is there any way to control them via a long range WiFi module on the Pi itself. So then I use my phone and connect it to the hotspot from the Pi to control the GPIO pins.
I hope somebody can help me.
I appreciate it!

Thanks!

Comment: Controlling pins directly from outside is not possible. What usually is done is installing a webserver on the pi and write some scripts like for instance a php script. The android device can then call the script with `"http://192.168.0.3/myscript.php?pin13=yes&pin8=no"`. Then the script will set the pins accordingly. If your Android device has a long range wifi module you can do it.

Comment: But is it possible to install a new WiFi module on the Raspberry Pi? So the signal is strong enough for the Android device.

Comment: You should ask that in a pi forum.

Comment: @blackapps Size note: _http**s**_. And authorization is missed/ :-)